# Golang Gorm not creating table with constraints

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm, go-gin

I'm working on a Gin app with Gorm. Currently, I've got the following struct which represents a model:

```
// Category represents a category object in the database
type Category struct {
    Name        string `json:"name" gorm:"size:60,unique,not null"`
    Description string `json:"description" gorm:"size:120"`
    Parent      uint   `json:"parent"`
    Active      bool   `json:"active" gorm:"default:true"`
    gorm.Model
}
```

as you can see, there are some constraints such as `size`, `unique`, and `not null`.

When I run the migration
`db.AutoMigrate(&entities.Category{})`

the table is in fact created, but not with the specified constraints.
Inspecting the table's DDL, here's how it is being created:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `name` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 1,
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_categories_deleted_at` (`deleted_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [doc](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html), I believe you should use semicolon (`;`) instead comma (`,`) between tag constraints declaration

```golang
type Category struct {
    Name        string `json:"name" gorm:"size:60;unique;not null"`
    Description string `json:"description" gorm:"size:120"`
    Parent      uint   `json:"parent"`
    Active      bool   `json:"active" gorm:"default:true"`
    gorm.Model
}
```

Comment: my bad, that was indeed the issue. I appreciate your help.

Comment: how to use unsigned?

Comment: @Nux sorry, what exactly do you mean with how to use unsigned?

Comment: I want interger type stored in db to be `unsigned`. -23 is signed and 23 is unsigned. Right now it is possible to  insert negative number in my column but that is not what I intend. TLDR: I mean SQL unsigned. So how it works with gorm?

Comment: I asked a auestion here for more details. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989945/gorm-how-to-set-unsigned-interger-in-tags