# Gorm: How to set unsigned interger in tags

Tags: go-gorm

I have the following struct with which when I run AutoMigration I expect unsigned to be set on table field quantity `quantity` but it doesn't.

Here is the struct I use

```golang
type Item struct {
    ID           int        `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Quantity     int        `json:"quantity" gorm:"type:integer;not null;unsigned;"`

}
```

SQL generated without UNSIGNED

```sql
    "id" BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'nextval(''items_id_seq''::regclass)',
    "quantity" INTEGER NOT NULL,
```

How to make unsigned work with gorm and postgres? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try the data type `uint `

Comment: @NirajKumar it didn't work

Comment: yep it doesn't works for `int`. You can try running a sql query to alter the table to `int4`, and then run the migration script. Also, give it a try with `float32`. Seems like if the column exists already, the migration is only able to alter the column with some data types. This works `int4 -> numeric (in postgres)`, but not able to revert it to `int4` with the gorm migration, probably some bug or it must be done to protect the data?

Comment: @NirajKumar Thanks for response I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`gorm:"type:decimal(16,2) unsigned;not null;"`
```

don't put a semicolon between a data type and unsigned.
Worked in mysql, postgres dont have type unsigned

Comment: I didn't know that postgres lacks unsigned. Thanks